# CSS preprocessor that runs in IE6

Tags: javascript, less, internet-explorer-6, stylus

I'm looking for a CSS pre-processor that runs in IE6. Obviously it needs to be written in Javascript; does Less, Stylus, or any other JS-based CSS preprocessor work in IE6?

(It's for a widget which optionally lets the embedder set up some variables, hence needs to work in the browser and support older browsers.)

Comment: IE6? 2 years ago, IE6 market share [was already less than 1%](http://threatpost.com/en_us/blogs/updated-ie6-market-share-dips-below-1-us-microsoft-celebrates-010412)

Comment: It can be a lot higher in certain communities though, so someone embedding the widget might be ruling out, say, 10% of their audience. Given this is just string manipulation, there's an okay chance anything that works in IE7/8 works in IE6 anyway.

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: Gave up on this approach mostly for other reasons and didn't get an answer about IE6 compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason why Less, Sass, Stylus, etc can't work in IE6. They compile down to CSS. As long as you're not using CSS that's not supported in IE6 I don't see how any would be a problem.

If you're looking for a compiler that runs in the browser and supports IE6, you might be hard pressed. Even the insurance industry has moved on from IE6...

Answer (score -1):

You can use less css for it,

http://lesscss.org/

Its the dynamic stylesheet language. It uses a simple JavaScript file. Embed it in your template and start using it. It is easy to use...